# Grep command - List files starts with string and extension

Tags: ubuntu, grep, command

I am trying to grep the list of .log files present in a folder using grep.

I have tried the following command

```
ls | grep "gen.*" --include =\*.log | wc -l
```

But the above commands counts the other file types as well. I have .txt and .html and .doc file starts **gen** . It is counting that file as well. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try `ls -lR gen*.log | wc -l`

Comment: Or, `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "gen*.log" -printf x | wc -c`

Comment: Another idea: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*/gen\(\.[^/]*\)?\.log$" -printf x | wc -c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this instead :

`find . -type f -iname "gen.*.log" | wc`

find is easily used to search in file names, whereas grep mostly to search in contents.

Your version can't work as your grep uses the output of `ls` to search in. --include and --exclude are to be used with a recursive grep (grep -r).

If you still want to use grep, it would be like this :

`ls | grep -e '^gen.*log' | wc -l`